# Problema na busca por colunas especificas do BD - JSF

Tags: java, jsf, maven, xhtml

Quando retorno todos os valores do banco, dar certo. No entanto se busco somente pelas colunas `id, celular, cpf, nome, status` para listar na tabela, retorna erro. Seria o tipo de retorno que está errada? Poderiam me dar um exemplo que funcione? Agradeço desde já.

Erro a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha Entidade Pessoa possui esses atributos:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

private Date data; // DATA 

private String nome; // NOME 

private String cpf; // CPF 

private String celular; // NUMERO DE CONTATO

private String usrAteracao; // USUARIO QUE ALTEROU

private String status; // INFORMA SE ESTA PENDENTE OU CONCUIDA

private byte[] imagem; // IMAGEM
```

Meu bean:

```
...
private List<Pessoa> listaPessoa;
...
// Lista Pessoa
public void listaPessoa(){
    try {
        listaPessoa = pessoaDAO.listaPessoa("PENDENTE");

        System.out.println("Lista: "+listaPessoa ); // imagem abaixo
        quant_na_lista = 0;
        for (Pessoa q : listaPessoa ) { // NÃO ENTRA NESSA CONDIÇÃO
            quant_na_lista += 1;
        }   
        onlistaPessoa();
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    
}   

// Lista pessoa
public List<Pessoa> onlistaPessoa(){
    return listaPessoa;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No meu DAO não busco todas as colunas.

```
// LISTA DE RETORNO DE PESSOA
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Pessoa> listaPessoa(String status) {
    Query query = null;     
    try {
        query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT id, celular, cpf, nome, status FROM Pessoa where status = :status");
        query.setMaxResults(2);
        query.setParameter("status", status);
        
        return (List<Pessoa>) query.getResultList();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Minha tabela xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{listaPessoaBean.listaPessoa}" paginator="true" rows="10" var="pessoa"  emptyMessage="Nenhuma pendente!" paginatorPosition="bottom">
    
     <f:facet name="header">
           <label>Pendentes</label>
     </f:facet>

    <p:column headerText="Nome" style="width: 15%;text-align:center" sortBy="#{pessoa.nome}" filterBy="#{pessoa.nome}">
        <h:outputText value="#{pessoa.nome}" />
    </p:column>
    
    <p:column headerText="CPF" style="width: 15%;text-align:center" sortBy="#{pessoa.cpf}" filterBy="#{pessoa.cpf}" >
        <center><h:outputText value="#{pessoa.cpf}" /></center>
    </p:column>
 
    <p:column headerText="Contato"  style="text-align:center">
     <center> <h:outputText value="#{pessoa.celular}" /></center>
    </p:column>
    
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retorne assim pelo DAO, isso resolve o problema:

```
public List<Pessoa> listaPessoa(String status) {
    Query query = null;     
    try {
        query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT s.id, s.celular, s.cpf, s.status FROM Pessoa s where status = :status");
        query.setMaxResults(2);
        query.setParameter("status", status);
        
        List<Object[]> objs = query.getResultList();
        
        List<Pessoa> pessoa = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();
        
        // Retorna os Objects do select para a List
        for (Object[] o : objs) {
               
             Object[] aux = o;
             Pessoa s = new Pessoa();
              s.setId(Long.parseLong(aux[0].toString()));
              s.setCelular(aux[1].toString());
              s.setCpf(aux[2].toString());
              s.setStatus(aux[3].toString());
              pessoa.add(s);
        }
        
        return pessoa;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente isso

```
 public List<Pessoa> listaPessoa(String status) {
        Query query = null;     
        try {
           String hql = " from Pessoa p where p.status = :status;

           Query query = em.createQuery(hql);
           query.setParameter("status", status);
           query.setMaxResults(2);
            
           return query.getResultList();
    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Faltou fechar a string `String hql = " from Pessoa p where p.status = :status;`